# Catching Multiple Exceptions - calling methods not present in Exception on the caught exception

Tags: java, exception, catch-block

```
public class try
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if(true)
                throw new A();
            if(true)
                throw new B();
        }
        catch( A | B e)
        {
            e.doit();
        }
    }
}

class A extends Exception
{
    public void doit() {}
}

class B extends Exception
{
    public void doit() {}
}
```

This doesn't compile

```
18: error: cannot find symbol
        e.doit();
         ^
symbol:   method doit()
location: variable e of type Exception
```

The variable `e` seems to end up as type `Exception` rather than the actual type - this seems logical because at compile type the compiler doesn't know what kind is going to be thrown. However, is there a way to make this work without making `A` & `B` both derive from some common base class or implement a common interface?

Comment: `Exception` is the only type it can be, as this is the only type `A` and `B` have in common. If creating an intermediate class is not an option, why not just use separate catch blocks?

Comment: sorry to interrupt. What is that or symbol doing in the catch block? What is it called? Haven't done java for couple of years so bit behind.

Comment: @OliverWatkins - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#multiple - this is Java 7 feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well no, because Java doesn't support [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Doing an `instanceof` and casting `e` to either `A` or `B` is obviously going to work, but what you probably want to do in this case is doing it in the traditional way of *writing two catch blocks*.

I mean, it makes sense, right? Multi-catch is appropriate in the case where you want to treat different kinds of exceptions *equally*. In this case, the behaviour can be drastically different (even if the methods are named the same).

Comment: ...otherwise catch all in catch(Exception e)

Answer (score 1):

You should just create a super class that both A and B extend, give that class an doIt() method, and then implement that method for both A and B, like this:

```
  class A extends C {
    public void doit() {
    }
  }

  class B extends C {
    public void doit() {
    }
  }

  abstract class C extends Exception {
    public abstract void doit();
  }
```

You can then catch C, like this:

```
try
{
  if(true)
    throw new A();
  if(true)
    throw new B();
}
catch( C e)
{
  e.doit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If not using interface, can I use instanceof instead. A little tedious. BTW, why you don't write two catch block to catch the two exceptions separately.

```
public class Try
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if(true)
                throw new A();
            if(true)
                throw new B();
        }
        catch(A | B e)
        {
            if(e instanceof A){
                ((A) e).doit();             
            }else if (e instanceof B){
                ((B) e).doit();             
            }
        }
    }
}

class A extends Exception 
{
    public void doit() {}
}

class B extends Exception 
{
    public void doit() {}
}
```

---

Another way is using reflect.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Try
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            if(true)
                throw new A();
            if(true)
                throw new B();
        }
        catch(A | B e)
        {
            Class cls = e.getClass();  
            Method doit = cls.getMethod("doit");
            doit.invoke(e, null);
        }
    }
}

class A extends Exception
{
    public void doit() {}
}

class B extends Exception
{
    public void doit() {}
}
```

---

The interface may help.

Comment: Updated my question - I had already said "without making both of them derive from some common base class" - added implementing a common interface to that line.

Comment: @user93353 I don't suggest you using the Java reflection. But I think it works here.